# C - Values of structures' attributes change after a printf

Tags: c

I've been working on a RPG in C recently and i've come accross a problem. My program has a bunch of structures (player, mob, equipment etc..), some of them containing lists.

Everything has been working just fine, so I created a character and started printing some of his attributes to test them :

```
Player* playerCharacter = createPlayer("Boby", 10, getRaces(), getItems(), createFirstInventory(), getUsable());

printf("Your helmet is %s\n", playerCharacter->mob->equipment->head->name);
printf("Your helmet is %s\n", playerCharacter->mob->equipment->head->name);
```

The first printf works just fine, but the second one(or any more after that) prints like a long list of random characters (or numbers depending on what i try to print) instead of the actual name of the helmet.

I've been thinking that it had to do with memory allocation (i'm using malloc to create my lists for exemple) or with the "->" operator, but couldn't find the answer to my problem.

Here are the declaration of structures used :

```
typedef struct Player
{
    int id;
    Mob* mob;
    int lives;
    int gold;
    StuffItem** playerInventory;
    StuffItem** itemsList;
    UsableItem** playerPotions;
    UsableItem** potionsList;
} Player;

typedef struct Mob
{

    int id;
    char* name;
    MobRace* mobRace;
    int hp;
    int attack;
    int relativeDefense;
    int absoluteDefense;
    int dodge;
    Equipment* equipment;
} Mob;

typedef struct Equipment{
    StuffItem* head;
    StuffItem* chest;
    StuffItem* leggings;
    StuffItem* boots;
    StuffItem* leftHand;
    StuffItem* rightHand;
} Equipment;

typedef struct StuffItem
{
    char* name;
    int goldValue;
    // typeId : 0=head, 1=chest, 2=leggings, 3=boots, 4=lefthand, 5=righthand
    int typeId;
    int hp;
    int attack;
    int relativeDefense;
    int absoluteDefense;
} StuffItem;
```

And my createPlayer function :

```
Player* createPlayer(char name[20], int pointsToAttribut, DlistRace* racesList, DlistItems* itemsList, DlistItems* firstInventory, DlistUsable* potionsList)
{
    //Dlist* playerItemList = dlist_new();
    //createItemsList();

    StuffItem* phead = returnListElement(itemsList,0);
    StuffItem* pchest = returnListElement(itemsList,1);
    StuffItem* plegs = returnListElement(itemsList,2);
    StuffItem* pboots = returnListElement(itemsList,3);
    StuffItem* plefthand = returnListElement(itemsList,4);
    StuffItem* prighthand = returnListElement(itemsList,5);

    Equipment* playerEquipment = Equipment_ctor(phead, pchest, plegs, pboots, plefthand, prighthand); 

    Mob* playerMob = Mob_ctor(0, name, returnListElementRace(racesList, 1), 100, 10, 50, 10, 10, playerEquipment);
    Player* playerCharacter = Player_ctor(0, playerMob, 3, 500, firstInventory, itemsList, selectFirstPotions(), potionsList);

    return playerCharacter;

}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Could you please add the delcaration of your structures playerCharacter, mob, equipment, head and name ? The functions that are called in the 1st line could be interesting to.

Comment: _The first printf works just fine, but the second..._ Those instructions are identical and sequential. Post a compilable code that gives the error you are asking about. Take a look at [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: My guess?  createPlayer() returns a pointer to a local stack var, ie. UB.

Comment: Please also upload code of `Player_ctor` and others which are like that.

Comment: @Martin James and @Paul Ogilvie are very likely to be right: the question is : does `Player_ctor` use `malloc` to create a `Player` object. If not, you should because rigth now you have an Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Great, Xely, posting the creator function! We now know the error can be in `returnListElement(), returnListElementRace, Equipment_ctor, Mob_ctor` or  `Player_ctor`. We need that code too, as you could have understood.

Answer (score 3):

> The first printf works just fine, but the second one [not].

This is indicative of you returning some data which is on the stack in your `createPlayer` which in the first `printf` call is still available and placed on the stack for the `printf` call, and is now overwritten by the `printf` call. Thus your data has been overwritten and the second `printf` prints garbage.

If you post `CreatePlayer` we can take a look at it.

Comment: Yes, prolly the whole of the 'playerCharacter' struct.is local to 'createPlayer()'  :(